# Better Grouping for Mongoose Aggregate Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A bit of background information on the structure of my collection. I've got various types of financial transactions, all saved into one collection using discriminatorKey. Here is an example:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5816346ef201a84e17a84899"),
    "accountUpdatedBy" : -9.95,
    "transactionAmount" : 9.95,
    "paidTo" : "Vimeo",
    "expenseCategory" : "advertising",
    "accountName" : "Bank Name",
    "transactionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T00:00:00Z"),
    "transactionID" : "",
    "transactionComment" : "",
    "transactionCategory" : "SelfEmploymentExpense",
    "transactionFee" : 0,
    "entryDate" : ISODate("2016-10-30T17:57:02.144Z"),
    "__v" : 0
```

What I need to do is gather all of the totals for all transaction types, grouped by year and month. After taking a look at some similar questions here, this is the best query I've come up with:

```
Transaction.findTransactionCategoryTotalsByMonth = function () {
return this
    .aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: {transactionCategory: "$transactionCategory", month: {$month: "$transactionDate"}, year: {$year: "$transactionDate"}},
            total: {$sum: "$transactionAmount"},
        }},
        {$project: {
            year: "$_id.year",
            month: "$_id.month",
            transactionCategory: "$_id.transactionCategory",
            total: "$total",
            _id: false,
        }}
    ])
    .sort({year: 1, month: 1, transactionCategory: 1});
};
```

However, this produces results like this:

```
 [ { total: 0,
    year: 2016,
    month: 8,
    transactionCategory: 'AccountUpdate' },
  { total:100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 8,
    transactionCategory: 'Other' },
  { total: 100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 8,
    transactionCategory: 'SelfEmploymentExpense' },
  { total: 100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 8,
    transactionCategory: 'SelfEmploymentIncome' },
  { total: 0,
    year: 2016,
    month: 9,
    transactionCategory: 'AccountUpdate' },
  { total: 100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 9,
    transactionCategory: 'CreditCardPayment' },
  { total: 100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 9,
    transactionCategory: 'Other' },
  { total: 100,
    year: 2016,
    month: 9,
    transactionCategory: 'SelfEmploymentExpense' } ]
```

The issues with that are pretty clear. Ideally, I'd like to find a way to consolidate the data a bit, to reduce iteration when formatting the response. Something that would allow me to nest in order to end up a result that looks like:

```
    [{year: 2016, 
    SomeTransactionType: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], // Amounts for each month in an array
    OtherTransactionType: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}]
```

Or any other way of getting the number of objects down, with more nesting.

Very grateful for any advice. And apologize ahead of time if this is something basic, as I'm very new to JavaScript and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`

```
Transaction.findTransactionCategoryTotalsByMonth = function () {
return this
    .aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: {year: {$year: "$transactionDate"},transactionCategory: "$transactionCategory"},
            total: {$push: "$transactionAmount"},
        }},
    {$group: {
            _id: "_id.year",
transactionCategoryArray : {$addToSet:{transactionCategory: "$_id.transactionCategory",transactionAmount:"$total"}}
      }},{$sort:{_id:-1}}
    ])
};
```

`